# MongoDB $text search

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, flask, search

```
query = { 
            "is_deleted"        : False, 
            "status_value"      : "PROSES"
        }

if keyword != "":
        query["$text"] = { "$search" : keyword }

db.db_konten.find(query)
```

I have a pymongo query using the text search of MongoDB. It works fine. But I found out that it cant searh the word **very** ? Is there a reason why. Im using python3 and Flask

Comment: Add some sample documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your text index is set to English, it will exclude certain stop words, including **very**.

If you're interested, the full list is in the [MongoDB source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt).

You can also override it by [setting the `$language` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) when creating the text index.